# Macbook Air 2013 OS X 10.8.2 acting funny

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Air 2013. Suddenly, on startup it shows a  sign, then the apple and it goes to disk utility. There I have 4 options. Restore from time machine, reinstall OS X, Get help online and disk utility.
I would like to reinstall OS X but that requires broad band Internet connection which I don't have. Is there any other way of getting around this and recover my OS X? By the way, I seem to have a disk 1 OS X 10.8.2 base system...
Can anybody help?

Comment: sorry the 10.8.2 will not help here since your OS is 10.9x, it is possible you have the OS recovery already installed, and if yes you wont need Internet.

Answer (score 1):

The 10.8.2 wont help most probably you were on 10.9x

Start with Disk Utility and see if you can repair your disk.

While in disk utility look if you have hidden partition called recovery.

If yes use the cmd-r to try to repair your os.

Comment: Yes. I have a Recovery HD and under it com.apple.boot.S; com.apple.recovery.boot and System.Under which one should I expect to find the co-driver?

Comment: Sorry. The cmd-r.